# React Native routing with redux: Error: Expected the reducer to be a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, routes, redux

I'm trying to make Redux handle my routing state in a React Native application. The component I use to handle routing is [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux).

The error message I receive is **"Expected the reducer to be a function"**. [Here is the full error.](https://pastebin.com/Hbye1wVE) I've been having this issue for a long time and can't figure this out. I'm understanding more and more Redux concepts but now I have to ask for help. Based on reading stackoverflow posts on the same issue, I find that it might be some export/import issues but neither me, my project members or my senior dev at work can see it.

Now, I have a minimum setup with 3 different classes, including my Router component. Keep in mind that I create the store from my main file App.js for simplicity.

Containers/App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
import { combineReducers, createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import routingReducer, { counter, userReducer } from './../Redux/Reducers';

const RouterWithRedux = connect()(NavigationRouter);

// Combine Reducers
const reducers = combineReducers({
    userReducer,
    routingReducer,
});

// create store...
const middleware = [/* ...your middleware (i.e. thunk) */];
const store = compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware))(createStore)(reducers);

export default class App extends Component {
  render () {

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <RouterWithRedux />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

Redux/Reducers.js

```
import { ActionConst } from 'react-native-router-flux';

const routingState= {
    scene: [],
};


const userState = {
    users: [],
}

// The Routing Reducer
export default function routingReducer(state = routingState, action = {}) {
    switch (action.type) {
        // focus action is dispatched when a new screen comes into focus
        case ActionConst.FOCUS:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                scene: action.scene,
            });

        // ...other actions

        default:
            return state;
    }
};

// The User Reducer
export function userReducer(state = userState, action = {}) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'USER_LIST_SUCCESS':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                users: action.users
            });
    }
    return state;
};
```

Navigation/MyExportedRouter.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Router, Scene, Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import SettingsContainer from './../Containers/SettingsContainer'
import LoginWrapper from './../Containers/LoginWrapper'

const myConnectedRouter = connect()(Router);
// TODO: Define Scene keys as "ENUMS": loginScreen -> TO_LOGIN
const scenes = Actions.create(
    <Scene key="root">
        <Scene initial key='TO_LOGIN' component={ LoginWrapper } title='LaunchScreen' hideNavBar />
        <Scene key='TO_SETTINGS_VIEW' component={ SettingsContainer } title='Monthly View'  />
    </Scene>
);

class MyExportedRouter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);'
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <myConnectedRouter scenes={scenes} />
        );
    }
}

export default MyExportedRouter;
```

Also keep in mind that react-native-router-flux  sends "THE_KEY" as an action to the reducer in Reducers.js. This is done through e.g. a button onPress="Actions.THE_KEY".

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that's how you create a redux store? Try declaring your store like this, as per the example in the [createStore docs](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/api/compose.md).

```js
const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  applyMiddleware(...middleware)
);
```

Comment: I've tried to simply just call createStore(reducers) which doesn't work. I don't think the issue is exactly here, but it could be as my error message mentions it. I'm really stuck on this one.